# Amcharts html label for pie chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, amcharts

I have a pie chart built using Amcharts. Everything is working fine except the way `pie label` is rendring.

So i want my label to be like : **`US:`**`15%`

But i can not make `US` bold keeping `15%` lighten.

if I do

`labelText: "<strong>[[title]]:</strong> [[percents]]%`

Then the output label is `<strong>US:</strong>15%`

Can we do any trick using CSS/JS?

Comment: Please add some images. It makes it easier to see what the problem is.

Comment: I'm afraid, there's no way to do that. Those labels are not HTML, it's SVG, hence HTML tags like `<strong>` not working.

Comment: @martynasma any other way round for this?

Comment: Not that I know of. Sorry.

Comment: @martynasma thanks. Do you know is there any way by which i can make the color of label same as the color of it's pie.

Comment: Well, not directly. But you can use `labelColorField` to specify label color for each slice individually. Here's a demo: http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/90524b1c8f338562a340b5f297ea030a

Comment: Aah thank you so much.. That will work! 